# Foundation 5 Abide and Modal AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 5 and I can't seem to get Abide to work correctly on an modal form.

Form is called from:

```
<a href="/admin/edit_customer/<?= $order->id ?>/<?= $order->cust_id ?>" class="button tiny" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">Edit Customer</a>
```

and everything goes just fine, except abide never fires. Here's the form (abbreviated). In particular, I'm having issue with the email pattern.

```
<form data-abide action="/admin/edit_customer" method="POST">
<fieldset><legend>Edit Customer Information</legend>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <label class="prefix" for="fname">First Name <small>required</small>    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-8 columns">
                <input type="text" id="fname" required value="<?= $c_info->fname ?>"     placeholder="<?= $c_info->fname ?>" name="c_fname">
                <small class="error">First name is required.</small>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-4 columns">
            <label for="lname" class="prefix">Last Name <small>required</small></label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 columns">
            <input type="text" required value="<?= $c_info->lname ?>" placeholder="<?= $c_info->lname ?>" name="c_lname" id="lname">
            <small class="error">Last name is required.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large-9 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label class="prefix" for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="text" name="c_email" pattern="email" id="email" value="<?= $c_info->email ?>" required>
            <small class="error">Need a valid email</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <a href="#" class="button tiny radius" target="_blank">Email Customer</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).foundation('abide','events');</script>
```

To the end, but that just made the modal fail.

Anyone have any fixes? Or, have any ideas of where to start on this?

Answer (score 2):

HOT DIGGITY!

So, turns out that line

```
$(document).foundation('abide','events');
```

was the right thing to do, but it changed in Foundation 5 to:

```
$('#your_form_id').foundation({bindings:'events'});
```

Hope that helps someone else!!!